# Get single token for Microsoft Graph API and Microsoft Dataverse Web API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-platform

I am using Microsoft Graph API and Microsoft Dataverse Web API in a single applications. Due to this, I have to get 2 different access tokens for each by addding different value of `resource` key. Is it possible to generate a single token that can be used for both ?

Answer (score 0):

This might also be achieved through RefreshToken to get an AccessToken to the individual endpoints with the same scopes as authorized when you requested the graph access (scopes).

E.g. If you requested Mail.Read (https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read) you can get back to the token issuing endpoint with the refresh_token with scope="https://outlook.office.com/mail.read" and get an accesss_token for this endpoint.

you can use the On-Behalf-Of Grant to exchange the token with a new one, only this time addressed for the resource you need. Please refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#saml-assertions-obtained-with-an-oauth20-obo-flow).